# Kendo NavBar/TabStrip SPA Setup

Tags: angular-kendo

Below is an example of trying to use the NavBar/TabStrip and Mobile List View within an Angular SPA.  My List always takes up as much space as needed, instead of having the NavBar and TabStrip anchor at the top and bottom of the form, while allowing the ListView to scroll.  Can you not use the ng-view to make the NavBar/TabStrip anchor?  This should be a common look and feel for using Angular and kendo.ui.core but I can't find an example.  I have the main form and the partial form code below.

```
MAIN FORM
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="casenote_app"> 
<head>
<title></title>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui"/>
<!-- Makes your prototype chrome-less once bookmarked to your phone's home screen -->

<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"/>

<link href="content/kendo/2014.2.716/kendo.bootstrap.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/kendo/2014.2.716/kendo.ui.core.min.js"></script>

<script src="scripts/kendo/2014.2.716/kendo.angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


 <div kendo-layout data-id="viewbinding">

    <header data-role="header">
         <div kendo-mobile-nav-bar>
            <div kendo-mobile-view-title>NDB Casenotes</div>
            <button kendo-mobile-button data-align="left">Back</button>
        </div>

    </header>


     <div ng-view="" data-layout="viewbinding"></div>

    <div data-role="footer">

         <div kendo-mobile-tab-strip k-on-select="tabstripSelect(kendoEvent.item)">
            <a href="#/casenote" data-icon="">Casenote</a>
            <a href="#/participants" data-icon="">Participant</a>
            <a href="#/goalsobjectives" data-icon="">G/O</a>
            <a href="#/activities" data-icon="">Activities</a>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/controllers/clientcontroller.js"></script>

<script src="app/services/clientfactory.js"></script>

</body>
</html>

PARTIAL FORM
<div class="container">


<div data-role="View"> 

<ul kendo-mobile-list-view  k-data-source="clients" k-template="clienttemplate" k-append-on-refresh="true" k-pull-to-refresh="true"></ul>
```

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="clientViewTemplate">
    <div>#= last_name # </div>
</script>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, it appears Kendo on it's own handles some of the formatting needs that angular-kendo usage does not.  Below is an article that discusses the .css file need and I've included the code as well.  For the header to remain static the .header portion of the .css file is needed, and set the class of the control to "header".  The rest is utilized to keep the tabstrip at the bottom.  It works with the bootstrap .css file but doesn't seem to work so great with some of the other looks/feels.  I've included the html for that portion as well and the site reference.

http://developer.telerik.com/featured/announcing-support-for-kendo-ui-mobile-with-angularjs/

http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

```
body, html {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.header {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 1030;
 }

.content {
padding-top: 50px;
height: 100%;
}

.footer
{
position: fixed;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
margin-bottom: 0;
}

.footer, .push 
{
height: 4em;

}


.wrapper 
{
 min-height: 100%;
 height: auto !important;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto -4em;
}


    <div kendo-layout data-id="viewbinding">

    <header data-role="header" class="header">
         <div kendo-mobile-nav-bar>
            <div kendo-mobile-view-title>NDB Casenotes</div>
            <button kendo-mobile-button data-align="left">Back</button>
        </div>

    </header>



   <div class="wrapper">

      <div class="content" ng-view=""></div>

    <!--  </div> -->

    <div class="push"></div>
           </div>

    <div data-role="footer" class="footer">

         <div kendo-mobile-tab-strip k-on-select="tabstripSelect(kendoEvent.item)">

            <a href="#/casenote" data-icon="compose">Casenote</a>
            <a href="#/participants" data-icon="contacts">Participant</a>
            <a href="#/goalsobjectives" data-icon="organize">Goals/Objs</a>
            <a href="#/activities" data-icon="action">Activities</a>

        </div>

    </div>

 </div>
```